# angularjs ng-repeat is very slow with heavy data

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with one board system. In which there are cards need to display as well are card can be drag and drop into the board.

There are **n number of row and column possible in board** and **card can be drag and dropped to any row and column**.

So I have implemented it with **nested ng-repeat** and it is working correctly.

**but when there are more then 300 cards are on board then it is taking to much time to load around 8000ms to 9000ms.**

as data is more and used nested ng-repeat so there are so many iterations.

lazy load is not possible due to need to display all cards in single board.

So in this case how can I improve performance to render board with ng-repeat or any other alternatives.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve ng-repeat performance is using it with track by:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array track by item.property"> </div>
```

Or try this if the item property isn't unique:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array track by $index"> </div>
```

Comment: I have already used
<div ng-repeat="item in array track by $index"> </div>

i am trying
<div ng-repeat="item in array track by item.property"> </div>

Comment: I have tried <div ng-repeat="item in array track by item.property"> </div>
it reduces time to 4000ms to 5000ms from 9000ms.
I checked all filters and every think responding quickly but it is taking time to re-rendering.

Comment: You can use to one-time bindings in AngularJS like this:                         `<div ng-repeat="item in ::array track by item.property"> {{::item.property}} </div>` when you use this syntax changes made to the object will not be updated. One-time binding is very simple, from the docs: One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value.